# C#'s application configuration "app.config" file... how to store collections?

Tags: c#, app-config

I am in the process of writing a service using C# and I need to store a list of strings within the *app.config* file. I have 161 of these.

How can I store this information in the *app.config* file? There must be a way, because these are strongly typed values and thus I'm supposed to easily use any valid .NET type in the code to access them!

I want to avoid having one value that uses a comma-separated list for obvious performance issues.

Comment: How would a comma-separated list impact performance?  I've used comma-delimited string in config files before and not noticed any performance issue.

Comment: @Tim - I agree that performance if probably not the driver for this, but for 161 items, a comma separated list is not the most elegant solution in your app.config file. Given that app.config is XML and will be de-serialized anyway, it is much nicer to store your data in XML inside it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use Microsoft’s Visual Studio 2010.

1. In **Solution Explorer**, expand the **Properties** node of your project.
2. In **Solution Explorer**, double-click the *.settings* file in which you want to add a new setting. The default name for this file is *Settings.settings*.
3. In **Settings Designer**, set the **Name**, **Type**, **Scope**, and **Value** for your setting. Each row represents a single setting.
4. The Type that you need is `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`. This can be located after clicking **Browse** at the end of the DropDownList that appears when you click to set the **Type**.
5. Click on the button that appears towards the end of the **Value** TextBox.
6. Type in your strings, one-by-one, in the dialog that appears.

[image: This is how it goes.]

Answer (score 10):

There is a good article about storing lists (or any custom object) in your app.config files in [Best Way Of Saving Lists in App.Config](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/725cb4ab-d723-4dda-9215-7f444c8658cd/)

Essentially, you create an object that represents the data.

```
public class MyConfig
{
    public string[] myList;
    public string someOtherValueIfYouWant;
}
```

And write a config handler for it...

```
public class ConfigSectionHandler : IConfigurationSectionHandler
{
    public const string SECTION_NAME = "MyConfig";
    public object Create(object parent, object configContext, XmlNode section)
    {
        string szConfig = section.SelectSingleNode("//MyConfig").OuterXml;
        MyConfig retConf = null;

        if (szConfig != string.Empty || szConfig != null)
        {
            XmlSerializer xsw = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyConfig));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(szConfig));
            ms.Position = 0;
            retConf = (MyConfig)xsw.DeSerialize(ms);
        }
        return retConf;
    }

}
```

And this allows you to put the following XML in your app.config file...

Tell app.config about your cool config section

```
<configSections>
    <section name="MyConfig" type="ConfigSectionHandler,someAssembly" />
</configSection>
```

And then add your config section...

```
<MyConfig>
    <myList>First one</myList>
    <myList>Second one</myList>
    <myList>Keep going</myList>
    <myList>And so on</myList>
    <someOtherValueIfYouWant>some non array config</someOtherValueIfYouWant>
</MyConfig>
```

Comment: WARNING: This topic uses the System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler interface, which has been deprecated in the .NET Framework version 2.0. For an example that uses the System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection class, see How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score -3):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30178144/878539

StringCollection is **NOT** recommended in VS2015RC for the purpose of annoyance'ness when loading the properties settings dialog window for the project and re-saving the data.   If you have a dozen entries for serializeAs="Xml" and everytime you open the properties window it will popup with a dialog for EACH entry telling you to confirm overwrite.   Yes/No does absolutely nothing.

The data mismatch for each file will set this off and is a known issue.  See my other post related.

Use a workaround such as Custom Config storage or find a way to leave your collections out of the designer or app.config.  One or the other.

Viable solution only for those willing to put up with the nag dialog windows or rarely edit the settings property information.